# T-SQL Truncate text and add number at the end to avoid duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I need to truncate data from a column to 10 characters.  However, I cannot have any duplicates, so I want any duplicates to end with ~1 for the first duplicate, ~2 for the second duplicate.  Here's an example of what I have:

```
Column
------
The ABC Company Inc.
The ABC Cooperative
XYZ Associates LLC.
```

I'd like the result to be:

```
Column
------
The ABC ~1
The ABC ~2
XYZ Associ
```

The end doesn't have to be ~1 or ~2, I just need something to make it unique after truncating.  There may be more than 3 or 4 duplicates after truncating.

So far, I'm just truncating and editing the table manually:

```
update Table set Column = Left(Column, 10) where len(Column) > 10
```

Comment: If you truncate "The ABC Company Inc." and "The ABC Cooperative" to 10 characters, you'll be left with "The ABC Co" for both, resulting in a duplicate.

Comment: The ABC ~1 IS 10 characters

Comment: What if there are 10 or more duplicates?

Comment: Honestly, I'd just go and delete duplicates if there were 10 or more...lol...for my case, at most I've encountered was 5 duplicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you care about the first 8 characters, not the first 10, because you need to reserve slots for the additional number.

Assuming that you have fewer than 10 repeats, you can do this:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by left(col, 8) order by (select null)) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by left(col, 8) ) as cnt
      from t
update toupdate
    set col = (case when cnt = 1 then left(col, 10)
                    else left(col, 8) + '~' + cast(seqnum as char(1));
```

The same idea can be used for a `select`.

Comment: It's worth noting that the numbering is not guaranteed to be stable and that if rows are added or deleted the numbering will, in all likelihood, change. That doesn't make it wrong, but it might surprise the OP at some later date.

Comment: This looks like what I need.  I'm trying to modify the query but I'm having trouble with the first line `with toupdate as`. Am I suppsoed to add anything else to this code?  I replaced `toupdate` with the table I wanted to update.  SQL Management Studio says there's a syntax error near 'from t` n ot sure how to fix that...

Comment: @Peter . . . The table goes in the `from` clause between `from` and `t`.

Comment: Thanks!  I added `end` to the `case` statement, added a ColumnID for the Table so I could join it to make the updates happen.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
Declare @Table Table (Column1 varchar(50))
Insert into @Table values 
('The ABC Company Inc.'),
('The ABC Cooperative'),
('XYZ Associates LLC.')

Select NewColumn = Concat(substring(Column1,1,10),' ~',Row_Number() over (Partition By substring(Column1,1,10) Order by Column1))
 From @Table
```

Returns

```
NewColumn
The ABC Co ~1
The ABC Co ~2
XYZ Associ ~1
```

Comment: As Gordon mentionioned, the 10 could be 8

Answer (score 1):

The numbers are noisy, so I only add them when necessary:

```
select case when _r > 1 
    then Company + '~' + cast(_r as varchar(5)) 
    else Company end as Company 
from (
    select Company
        , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Company order by Company) as _r
    from(
        select left(Company, 10) as Company
        from MyTable
    ) x
) y
order by Company


Company
--------------
The ABC Co
The ABC Co~2
XYZ Associ
```

Comment: I like this solution, but how do I use this to update my existing table?  I can't add new tables to this database, the query kind of helps, but I still need to update the table on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table is COMPANY and the field is CompanyName.....
You'll have to tweek but hope it helps..

```
SELECT SUBSTRING( Q.Comp, 1, 5) + '~' + CONVERT(nvarchar(4), Row) as NewFieldValue FROM
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SUBSTRING( C.CompanyName, 1, 6) ORDER BY SUBSTRING( C.CompanyName, 1, 6)) AS Row,
SUBSTRING( C.CompanyName, 1, 6) as Comp
FROM COMPANY C
)Q
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (Column1 varchar(50))

INSERT INTO @Table VALUES
      ('The ABC Company Inc.')
    , ('The ABC Cooperative')
    , ('XYZ Associates LLC.')
    , ('Acme')
    , ('Ten Char 123')
    , ('Ten Char 132')
    , ('Ten Char 231')


;WITH FLen
    AS (
        SELECT Column1, LEFT(LEFT(Column1,13) + SPACE(13),13) + CHAR(164) AS Column2
            FROM @Table
        )

,TenCharPD -- Includes possible duplicates
    AS (
        SELECT Column1, LEFT(Column2,8) + 
            RIGHT('0' + CAST (
            (ASCII(SUBSTRING(Column2, 9,1)) +
            ASCII(SUBSTRING(Column2,10,1)) +
            ASCII(SUBSTRING(Column2,11,1)) +
            ASCII(SUBSTRING(Column2,12,1)) +
            ASCII(SUBSTRING(Column2,13,1)))%100
            AS NVARCHAR(2)),2) AS Column2
        FROM Flen
        )
,CullPD
    AS (
        SELECT Column1, Column2,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Column2 ORDER BY Column2) AS rowx
        FROM TenCharPD
        )

UPDATE t1
    SET Column1 = LEFT(Column2,9) +
    CASE rowx
        WHEN 1 THEN RIGHT(Column2,1)
        ELSE CHAR(rowx + CAST (RIGHT(Column2,1) AS INT) * 5 + 63)
        END
    FROM @Table t1
        JOIN CullPD cpd
            ON t1.Column1 = cpd.Column1

SELECT * FROM @Table
```

Comment: Is there a way for me to use this code to update my existing table on the fly?

Comment: As-in, you want to replace the values in Column1 with those from Column2?

Comment: Yes please.  Getting the query is good, but I need something to also update the columns as well, thanks!

Comment: Okay, there you go. It will not work if you have two identical company names because of the join in the update. That's easy enough to create if your original table also has a unique row identifier. I can show you if you need me to. I used 'Acme' to show that it works when the company name is shorter; and 'Ten Char 123' and 'Ten Char 456' to show how it works when the first parts are similar. I should have done 'Ten Char 123' and 'Ten Char 132' so you could see it comes out as 'Ten Char14' and 'Ten Char1b'. I'm gonig to edit it.

Comment: Discovered another bug that would fail to distinguish between 'Ten Char 132' and 'Ten Char 142' when 'Ten Char 123' and 'Ten Char 124' existed. Just replaced "ELSE CHAR(rowx+95)" with "ELSE CHAR(rowx + CAST (RIGHT(Column2,1) AS INT) * 5 + 85)". Obviously there are some limits but this should reduce them.

Comment: Okay, another edit. Sorry. I'm down to 63 instead of 85. If you want to see how it works, try 'Ten Char 123v' along with 132, 231, 213, 312 and 321. All six of those have a mod of 0 for the sum of the ASCII codes of characters 9-13 with respect to 100 (32 + 49 + 50 + 51 + 118 = 300. So it assigns the characters '00' as the final two characters. But the others have the same mod, so it uses 0A, 0B, 0C, 0D and 0E instead. If you change the 'v' to a 'w', you get 01, 0F, 0G, 0H, 0I and 0J.